# How to check if an object is being created for the first time with a custom primary key in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following setup in my models:

```
import uuid

class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    uuid = models.UUIDField(
        _('uuid'),
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        unique=True,
        primary_key=True,
    )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            # Do something
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Because of my default being overridden in my primary key field, the `# Do something` part of my function does not trigger, because at this point, `not self.pk` returns `False`. How can I fix this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Django will actually make a fetch to check if the primary key exists in that case, to decide whether to create or update, see: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L851

Comment: Therefore it is usually better *not* to use a custom primary key, but an autofield, since that will omit these queries.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Most of the queries on `MyModel` will happen through the `uuid` field, so making that the primary key would obviously speed those queries up. That was my initial reasoning behind doing it this way. However, do you think that keeping the primary key the default one, and making `db_index=True` on the `uuid` field is the best option here?

Comment: using a `db_index` is of course a good idea if it is the primary key (although most databases will probably make an index automatically since it is the pk anyway). But as said before, the problem is that Django can not make the distinction between created or not then. For every create query, it will first look if such record exists, and the unfortunate part is thus that you do two roundtrips to the db.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self._state.adding:
        # Do something
```